# Laravel Horizon Jobs not appearing

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I have started *Laravel Horizon* using `php artisan horizon` but the dashboard status says `Inactive`. Also, none of the processed queues appear on the dashboard.

I checked my supervisor (one):

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
| Name                                 | PID   | Status  | Workers           | Balancing |
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
| Macbook-Work.local-6hoI:supervisor-1 | 14480 | running | redis:default (3) | simple    |
+--------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

All jobs are actually processed:

> Horizon started successfully.
>      [2018-01-07 22:39:39] Processing: app\Events\GameResultEvent
>      [2018-01-07 22:39:39] Processed:  app\Events\GameResultEvent
>      [2018-01-07 22:39:39] Processing: app\Events\GameResultEvent
>      [2018-01-07 22:39:39] Processed:  app\Events\GameResultEvent

Why are my jobs not appearing in the Laravel Horizon dashboard?

Comment: Please specify what is causing the down votes.

Comment: Are you in the looking at the same code bases?

Comment: I don't know exactly what part of the code that would be relevant and I don't want to spit out all 999999 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Horizon could process jobs but the actual dashboard didn't work was that I executed the command `php artisan horizon` on my machine instead of the VM.

If you are using Laravel Horizon with Laravel Homestead, you need to start horizon **on the VM**.